# the expression must be a pointer to the full type of the object (2-dimensional array compare)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have made the function to check the equality of the symbols from 'symbols' array and text line from the text file, which is in 'line array'. But for some reason it needs some operations with pointers, although I don't use it. The 'symbols' in 'i' index can have for example (2, a, b, c), and the text line has one line from the text, which is come in by STDIN, and separated to the one line to 'line array' with function 'put_array' where [j] is line number and [i] is symbol number in line. So I need to do something with this error code:
*the expression must be a pointer to the full type of the object*

P.S. I haven't tested the function yet, since I haven't run the code, it may not work correctly due to incorrectly written actions.

```
char put_array()
{
  int lines = count_nlines();
  char c1;
  int i, j;
  char string[lines][j];
  for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; (c1 = getchar()) != '\n'; j++)
    {
       string[i][j] = getchar();
    }
  }
  return string;
}

void control_print(const char symbols[][], const char line_array[][])
{
  for(int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; symbols[k][i] != 0; i++) //err
    {
      line_array = put_array();
      for(int j = i; line_array[j] != '\n'; j++) //err
       {
         if (symbols[k][i] == line_array[j][i]) //err 
           {
             printf("%s", line_array); 
           }
       }

    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: _"P.S. I haven't tested the function yet, since I haven't run the code, it may not work correctly due to incorrectly written actions."_ Aha, so you want us to test it for you?? Can you give us debugging slaves the full code at least then, plz?

Comment: Enable extra warnings, and then try to build it yourself. You will get errors, and you will get warnings (which you should really treat as errors). There are *many* problems with the code that will be caught by the compiler.